# Does alcohol help with HDL cholesterol level?

Tags: alcohol, cholesterol

This [article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/269045-does-alcohol-raise-cholesterol-levels/) claims that drinking alcoholic beverages helps to increase HDL (i.e. "good cholesterol") levels.

> drinking moderate amounts of alcohol have been shown to improve "good" cholesterol levels and have been linked with reduced incidence of heart disease.
>
> [...]
>
> the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention recommends that only moderate amounts of alcohol are consumed. This amounts to one drink per day for women and two drinks per day for men. One drink is equivalent to 5 ounces of wine, a 12-ounce beer, or a 1.5 ounce shot of liquor.

A total of 24 ounces (about 700 ml) of beer a day for a man seems more than a "moderate amount" - perhaps enough to cause addiction.

Is there evidence that drinking that much alcohol reduces the mortality risk due to cholesterol more than it raises it due to the side-effects of drinking?

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Do you want to check the claim *Is drinking 2 beers a day moderate drinking* (BTW It is considered so in many countries, 3 seems to be the limit), or the claim *alcohol helps increasing HDL level*. I assume the latter.

Comment: @JanDoggen, why can't I have 2 question in the post?

Comment: 1. [Because those are the rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) 2. Because asking what amount is 'moderate' is an off-topic question for *this* particular site

Comment: I've edited the question to played down the opinion-based question "What is moderate drinking?" As the old joke goes, an alcoholic is anyone who drinks more than you. If you want to get a feel for how much other people drink, [this infographic](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2014/09/25/think-you-drink-a-lot-this-chart-will-tell-you/) about US adults may help.

Comment: @Oddthinking *more than it raises it due to the side-effects of drinking* Good addition.